# meaning of "Japan is about as far as you could get from Roseburg, Oregon"

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of the following sentence?

> Japan is about as far as you could get from Roseburg, Oregon, the farm town where she was born.

Comment: Welcome to ELL. This post actually contains two questions. You have already received an answer to your first question. I will edit your post to remove the second question, but feel free to make another post about that question alone.

Answer (score 1):

I think it means: Japan is as far as possible from Oregon. Japan is very far from Oregon. You can't get farther from that town if you're in Japan.

Answer (score 0):

Not literally as far away as one can get, but a figure of speech meaning it was a long ways away, either in straight mileage, or perhaps financially, or otherwise unachievable for other reasons.